# OptaPlanner: List of a planning variable in a planning entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I'm trying to generate a timetable automatically using OptaPlanner, I want to assign more than one collaborator(planning variable) to a single activity(planning entity) depending on a need. I guess I could do that if I could use a `List` as planning variable. I found out about the `PlanningListVariable` but can't figure out how to use it and can't find any use case with that.

This is how I used it:

```java
@PlanningEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class Activity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PlanningId
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "activity_label")
    private String activityLabel;

//    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "locationRange")
    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "locationRange")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "resource", "typeOfLocation" }, allowSetters = true)
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Location> location;

    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "collaboratorRange")
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "resource", "typeOfCollaborator" }, allowSetters = true)
    private List<Collaborator> collaborator;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "equipmentRange")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "resource", "typeOfEquipment" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Equipment equipment;

    ...
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
15-06-2022 17:00:58.296 DEBUG [restartedMain  ] Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\Florent\PlanningGenSp\target\classes\com\planning\sp\domain\TimeTable.class]
15-06-2022 17:00:58.345 DEBUG [restartedMain  ] Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\Florent\PlanningGenSp\target\classes\com\planning\sp\domain\Activity.class]
15-06-2022 17:01:02.956  WARN [restartedMain  ] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'probl
emChangedRepositoryEventListener' defined in file [C:\Users\Florent\PlanningGenSp\target\classes\com\planning\sp\config\ProblemChangedRepositoryEventListener.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'timeTableResource' defined in file [C:\Users\Florent\PlanningGenSp\target\classes\com\planning\sp\web\rest\TimeTabl
eResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path res
ource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org
.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName for entityClass (class com.planning.sp.domain.Activity) and because there are multiple variableNames ([collaborator, equipment, location, period]), it cannot be deduced automatically.
15-06-2022 17:01:03.092 ERROR [restartedMain  ] Application run failed
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean in
stantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName for entityClass (class com.planning.sp.domain.Activity) and because there are multiple variableNames ([collaborator, equipment, location, period]), it cannot be deduced automatically.
```

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet

Comment: PlanningListVariable is still under development, which is why it is not documented yet. It already works, but it has some rough edges. For production deployments, we still recommend using the current chaining model, which is fully documented.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický, thank  you, but how can implement that without the planningListVariable, i don't seem to see how to figure it out. Any help?

Comment: First of all, the list variable is a means of creating a sequence (as in the chained model), so it will not work for collaborators anyway. One way to implement collaborators could be to have different entities for different collaborators, and these entities would share the same activity problem fact.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický, yes that is the normal procedure when i want to assign single collaborators per activity, I've done that and it's working fine. What i want it to do instead is to assign multiple collaborators to the same activity, for example if i need 4 collaborators to perform a single activity then 4 collaborators should be assigned to that activity.

Comment: I understand. And what I am saying is that if you know there are 4 collaborators required, create 4 different entities for a single activity; each entity gets one collaborator, which we know how to handle. However, if you do not know how many collaborators are required, then that is a much bigger problem and I am not sure we have a good domain model for that.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický, Actually i don't know how many collaborators and the list of collaborators could be up to a thousand. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

> I want to assign more than one collaborator(planning variable) to a single activity(planning entity) depending on a need.

Don't use a `@PlanningListVariable` for this, because it will force that a collaborator is assigned to **exactly** one activity. You probably don't want *distinct-list* semantics.

Create a class `ActivitySeat` for each need per activity. Make that the @PlanningEntity with a @PlanningVariable to collaborator. If Activity needs to have a of `List<ActivitySeat>`, things get more complex (@DeepPlanningClone, constraints etc), so try to avoid that.

Philosophy: don't assign each thing to a list of collaborators (nor assign each collaborator to a thing) but instead assign each open seat in the thing to a collaborator.

See OptaPlanner docs chapter design patterns for the modelling guide.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is pretty much the same thing I suggested in my comments above. If you do not know ahead of time how many needs (collaborators) per activity, this approach won't work.

Comment: It's pain - but I have seen it work in the past, by creating "virtual seats". It's the only way I know how to actually solve this (besides dynamic number of entities which is unsupported). Basically before solving determine the maximum number of seats (=max collaborators) per activity. Create an ActivitySeat for each of those, and add a medium constraint (or heavily weighted soft constraint) to minimize the number of seats per activity.

Comment: The pain comes from having to determine that "maximum number of seats per activity". Too low, and you won't reach a feasible/optimal solution. Too high and your search space explodes (= reach solutions slower). Start with setting it equal to your number of collobarators (which is the upper bound for that maximum) and tweak it down by running on many realistic datasets.

Comment: Additionally, after all that, there's a high chance that pillar moves (or even custom moves) can improve solution quality dramatically.